# Проверка наличия элемента массива в обоих его частях

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Требуется создать массив, рандомно его заполнить, и после появляется задача:
Проверить значения первой половины массива на их наличие во второй его половине. В случае если элемент присутствует только в первой половине то добавить его во второй массив

Все это на языке C#
Как создать массив, заполнить его, я еще понимаю, но как выполнить задачу понятия не имею.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Проверить можно в цикле фор по второй половине

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаемся по ячейкам до середины, и каждую ячейку сравниваем с второй частью массива и при удачном совпадении НЕ добавляем в второй массив

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = 11; // Количество ячеек
int[] mass = new int[n];
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
{
    mass[i] = rnd.Next(0,10);
    Console.WriteLine("i: " + mass[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n/2;i+=1)
{
    bool goodNum = true;
    for(int u = 0; u < n/2; u+=1)
    {
        if(mass[i] == mass[mass.Length - u - 1])
        {
            goodNum = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(goodNum == true)
    {
        list.Add(mass[i]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Второй массив");
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: `if(goodNum == true)`  фии

Comment: Соглы, но для новчика лучше по макс подробно писать, и развернуто, что бы легче читалось :)